# Etcd is running but no etcd.service is found in systemd on coreos

Tags: vagrant, coreos, systemd, kubernetes, etcd

So I'm trying to setup a master Kubernetes node on coreos in vagrant.  I'm using the example master cloud-config, found here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/cloud-configs/master.yaml with the addition of this as the first units:

```
- name: etcd.service
  command: start
- name: fleet.service
  command: start
- name: docker-tcp.socket
  command: start
  enable: true
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Docker Socket for the API

    [Socket]
    ListenStream=2375
    Service=docker.service
    BindIPv6Only=both

    [Install]
    WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Once I vagrant up and vagrant ssh, I run `sudo systemctl status kube-apiserver` and find that `kube-apiserver` is down due to the fact it can't find `etcd.service`; however when I do `ps -ef | grep etcd` etcd is clearly running.  Is there some specific location for etcd.service in systemd or do I have to add a content field to the unit in the cloud-config or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the example master config is looking for `etcd2.service`, while the actual file is `etcd.service` so I changed it in the example units and everything worked.

**EDIT**

The reason why this worked and was an issue to begin with was that I was using the coresos vagrant box for parallels which is 300~ builds old from the current stable coreos build so it was missing etcd2 all together.

Comment: I can't accept this answer yet, because it's my own, but it fixed everything.